# JMeter variables not loading

Tags: jmeter

JMeter variables seems to not resolving at all.
I must be missing something crucial, because i never worked on JMeter before.

users.csv pattern:

```
$id, $username, $password, $email, $name, $surname, $isadmin
```

> (2,user1,user,user@example.com,user,user,0)

[image]

[image]

In the results view, the request POST is this:

```
POST data: username=%24%7Busername%7D&password=%24%7Bpassword%7D&submit_login=
```

I've also tried to put the variables without the brackets, and they still not resolving. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your **CSV Data Set Config**, check the filename is good to access your CSV, and Delimiter is the good one used in your CSV.

[image]

Then, check if your CSV begin with a line of "column name", and then, lines with data

[image]

And then, use the variable ! It should work like charm

[image]

**EDIT : Just for info, your test plan tree looks great. For me, i use it, pretty similar ;)**

[image]

Comment: In your CSV, you write the "$" char with column name ? if yes, you should not ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems i forgot to place the column line on top. I just tried it but it stills outputs to username and password. :(
Filepath (tried with absolute path and relative too) and delimiter is 100% correct. My column names in the csv are not starting with $.

Comment: Try removing the variable name field in your CSV Data set. This is not usefull if you use the same as declare in your CSV ;)

Comment: Ahh i forgot to put back the brackets in the parameter field :) Now it works fine. Thank you so much!